# PHP disable escaping in heredoc

Tags: php, javascript, escaping, heredoc

I have PHP which gives minified JS as output through `heredoc`. Look at this code:

`function prerefresh()`**{$**`("#len").empty();predata.forEach(item)}`

As I have bolded above, the `{$` disturbs my heredoc due to variable escaping.

Is there any way to disable or fix such escaping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have PHP which gives minified JS as output through

That's what you are doing wrong.

Don't do any output through heredoc - it makes absolutely no sense in PHP. Just close PHP tag and write whatever JS as is.

```
?>
function prerefresh(){$("#len").empty();predata.forEach(item)}
```

it's the most natural way.

Comment: there are some prefix to avoid collision. only PHP can make such changes inside js.

Comment: for the sake of closing php tag, you are true. just need extra effort when code is inside quotations.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP 5.3 + you could use [nowdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) it doesn't parse.

Answer (score 0):

It's in fact *variable replacement* that you want to disable. And it's *escaping* what you are looking for:

```
function prerefresh(){\$("#len").empty();predata.forEach(item)}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `\` backslash to escape the `$`. Resulting in `\$`